How can I change dynamically background color of body having iframe ckeditor 4
I'm unable to figure out how to modify the CKEditor 4 iframe's body background color. I've tried multiple solution but unable to figure out how can i achieve.
Expectation is that cell background color should be dynamically changed based on selected color
(function($, Drupal, CKEDITOR) {
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('cellbackgroundcolorplugin', {
    icons: 'backgroundIcon',
    init: function(editor) {

      // Adding/Creating command.
      editor.addCommand('cellBackground', {
        exec: function(editor) {
          if (style.checkActive(editor.elementPath(), editor)) {
            editor.removeStyle(style);
          } else {
            editor.applyStyle(style);
          }
        }
      });

      // Register the button, when the button plugin is enabled
      if (editor.ui.addButton) {
        editor.ui.addButton('CellBackgroungColorPlugin', {
          label: editor.config.backgroundIconLabel,
          command: 'cellBackground',
          toolbar: 'basicstyles',
          icon: editor.config.backgroundIcon
        })
      }
    },
  });
})(jQuery, Drupal, CKEDITOR);

